# Have a String stored in one class and call the same with value in other class

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a class where i get the value of the textfield, the code is below

> driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("voyage_in"))).sendKeys("1001");
>   String voyagein_id=driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("voyage_in"))).getAttribute("value");
>           System.out.println(voyagein_id);

I have declared String voyagein_id as global
I have another class where i call this and the code is :

> import Int_Script.Int_appointment --(This is the 2nd class)
> System.out.println(Int_barge_appointment.voyagein_id);

I run both the 2 class as a suite file and always the voyagein_id is showing null. 
I need to get the value of the 1st class in voyage_id and when the 2nd class runs the value of the voyagein_id must be input of the textfield.

Comment: Are you sure the `voyagein_id` is "global"? That means, is it a `public` (or at least package private) instance variable of the class, and not declared locally in a method? Are you sure it's not shadowed by a local variable named the same? From your code, it looks like you're redeclaring the variable which basically ignores the original one. Does it compile if you remove the `String` type declaration in your code snippet?

Comment: Yes it is global "public static String voyagein_id;" in the first script, it fetches the value of the voyagein_id and prints but for the 2nd it shows null

Comment: @ Slance , @Umamaheshwar - Thanks I got it, I have declared the Variable twice once in global and the other inside the method.Was dumb to uderstand first +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify your OR.properties file once and copy it at correct location where the code is looking. I think you have not updated the properties file correctly. I too faced the same problem day before yesterday only. I have updated the properties file where the jar file is copied, then it worked. Before that i too got Null value.

Are you running any Jar file or directly from Eclipse?

Comment: You mean to say that i have to update to the latest jar package ?

Comment: What i mean to say is, you are using OR.properties file to store the atrributes, right? if so, if u are creating a jar file for your code and running it from command prompt, then u have to copy the OR.properties file to the location where the jar file is located. That means copy the latest OR.properties file to the jar file location.

Comment: Yes i am using the OR.properties to store the attributes. I run using junit. Just right click and run as junit. Anyways I copied the properties file into the jar file location. then too didn't work. Is there any connection of what I did ?

Comment: even if i remove the properties file and directly give the Xpath rather than to call from the properties I do not get the value.

Comment: you are entering the numeric values in that field, right? is your entered value in this field is   driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("voyage_in"))).sendKeys("1001"); is stored or not?

Comment: ya it's stored in voyagein_id and prints it in syso statement.

Comment: String voyagein_id=driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("voyage_in"))).getAttribute("value"); System.out.println(voyagein_id); The result is stored in the java file itself. Am i right? Does that have to do with property file.